# C string handling function to get substring

Tags: c++, c, string

I remenber a function in C or C++ that can do something like this:

```
string = "Hello my name is: 1234567 have a good day!"
function(string, "Hello my name is: %s have a good day!", substring)
```

and substring would be `1234567`. What `function` is that?

Comment: You're looking for [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Not very sure, but maybe [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) can help?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Sir, you beat me by 9 seconds. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, you can do that with [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Of course, there is no `string` datatype in C, though:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char string[] = "Hello my name is: 1234567 have a good day!";

  char substring[32];
  if(sscanf(string, "Hello my name is: %31s have a good day!", substring) == 1)
  {
    printf("got '%s'\n", substring);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) is the function that you search.

Comment: @simonc No, that would be `snprintf()`. Print for output, scan for input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to extract the number and not really so much the substring.

If your prefix string always begins with the format: "Hello my name is: " You can do:

```
const auto size = strlen("Hello my name is: ");
int substring = stoi(string.substr(size));
```

If you are unsure of your prefix, then I'd recommend a regex:

```
smatch m;
regex_search(string, m, regex(".*?(-?\\d+)"));
int substring = stoi(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for sscanf, but you probably want C++ regular expressions.

Start with a `std::regex`:

```
std::regex re( "Hello my name is: \b(\w+)\b have a good day!" );
```

Then put it into a function:

```
std::string get_name( std::string const& src ) {
  static std::regex re( R"-(Hello my name is: (\w+) have a good day!)-" ); 
  std::smatch results;
  bool bworked = std::regex_match( src, results, re );
  if (!bworked) return {};
  // Assert(results.size() >= 2);
  if (results.size() < 2) return {};
  return results.str(1);
}
```

This gives you a lot more control than `sscanf` with only a bit more work.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a3051454b2bd05c)

Going beyond regular expressions reaches full on parsing.

This solution uses C++11 features.  Some compilers have `<regex>` headers that are basically stubs as well, so check compiler support.